# email is not displaying inside image

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

Hi I have a page where after confirmation email is displaying. I want to display that email inside image link.

For this I have used this code, but I get email variable null here.

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 var formData = function() {  var query_string = (location.search) ? ((location.search.indexOf('#') != -1) ? location.search.substring(1, location.search.indexOf('#')) : location.search.substring(1)) : '';  
var elements = [];  
if(query_string) {     
    var pairs = query_string.split("&");     
    for(i in pairs) {     
        if (typeof pairs[i] == 'string') {           
            var tmp = pairs[i].split("=");           
            var queryKey = unescape(tmp[0]);           
            queryKey = (queryKey.charAt(0) == 'c') ? queryKey.replace(/\s/g, "_") : queryKey;   
            elements[queryKey] = unescape(tmp[1]);      
             }    
       } 
 }  
return {     
    display: function(key) {         
        if(elements[key]) {           
             document.write(elements[key]);         
         } 
         else {         
               document.write("<!--If desired, replace everything between these quotes with a default in case there is no data in the query string.-->");          
          }     
  }   
} 
}
(); </script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Offer Conversion: Safe Binary Trades -->
<script type="text/javascript">formData.display("email")</script>
<img src="http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub="email"    width="1" height="1" />

<!-- // End Offer Conversion -->
</body></HTML>
```

If you look at the last lines of code you can see `formData.display("email")`, it uses to display email, it is working fine, but its not working in case of

```
<img src="http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub="email"    width="1" height="1" />
```

I have tried by passing `formData.display("email")` instead of `email`, but it still returns blank.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly what your question is, or exactly what you're trying to do, but you may want replace

```
src="http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub="email"
```

with

```
src='http://mountainfallsmedia.go2cloud.org/SL22?adv_sub="email"'
```

(Note the single quotes encapsulating your url.)

Comment: i want to display email of user inside image,but in my code i get nothing in email variable.